# Some Elements Aren't Being Changed Even Though They Should Be

Tags: javascript

I want to make it so when I press a button and make an element appear, then press another and make another element appear, but it won't work. My current code is this:

```
function login() {
    var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
    if (username == "Ethan" && password == "Horton") {
        document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "Logged In: Ethan";
        document.getElementById("p1").style.visibility = "hidden";
        document.getElementById("Logout").style.visibility = "visible";
    } else if (username == "Person" && password == "Password") {
        document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "Logged In: Person";
        document.getElementById("p1").style.visibility = "hidden";
        document.getElementById("p1").style.visibility = "hidden";
        document.getElementById("Logout").style.visibility = "visible";
    } else {
        alert("Incorrect User/Pass");
    }
}
```

As you can see, I need to change quite a bit of things, but it won't do so. Help?

Demo Here: http://jsfiddle.net/dX28k/

Comment: Please provide more context, proof to the issue etc.. Include a demo possibly.

Comment: Added a Demo. Review it and please help.

Comment: Check this fiddle could be what you are looking for http://jsfiddle.net/szUnC/. Also please explain in the question what you want, what you tried, what your issue is.

Comment: A quick note, I'm using Cloud9 because it is more organized, but I am only having problems with Cloud9.

Comment: Fixed, with a bit of editing on your JSFiddle I got it working. Can you answer the question with just this? ; http://jsfiddle.net/szUnC/

Comment: What did you change.. :) Is that it?

Comment: I just did something to make it the way I wanted it. It didn't affect how it worked, and yes that is it.

Answer (score 0):

**Quick & Easy Solution**

Make sure you use single quotation within double quotation in your HTML.

```
onclick="document.getElementById('p1').style.visibility='visible'"
```

**Proper Solution**

- Make sure you always separate Javascript, HTML, CSS instead of clustering them all together.
- onclick event, for instance, should be done without inserting onclick attribute to a button tag.
- Use strict equality to avoid mismatching type (===).

http://jsfiddle.net/8dQNP/2/

Comment: Hate to burst your bubble, but I already have this solved. Thanks though.